# Overriding ServiceStack Templates with Embedded Resources

Tags: servicestack

Service stack documentation explains that templates for meta and operation pages may be overridden using static files.

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Virtual-file-system

This works well, however, I would prefer to deploy all my resources as embedded resources.

My assumption was that by registering my EmbeddedResourceSources in the hostConfig, that they would take precedence over the existing service stack templates but that does not seem to be the case:

```
     SetConfig(new HostConfig
        {
            EmbeddedResourceSources = {typeof(ApiUiResource).Assembly},
            EmbeddedResourceBaseTypes = {typeof(ApiUiResource)},

        });
```

The above works to serve all my other files, but the default pages for the meta and operations pages are still shown. Is what I am attempting to do possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Config.EmbeddedResourceBaseTypes` contains the order by which the embedded resource virtual files are loaded, so you'll need add yours at the start of the list to take precedence:

```
var config = new HostConfig
{
    EmbeddedResourceSources = {typeof(ApiUiResource).Assembly},
};
config.EmbeddedResourceBaseTypes.Insert(0,typeof(ApiUiResource));
SetConfig(config);
```

An alternative solution is to override `GetVirtualFileSources()` in your AppHost to change the order which the virtual file sources are returned, see the [docs for an example of this](http://docs.servicestack.net/html-css-and-javascript-minification#minify-dynamic-razor-views).